# How can I filter by object key from array of object in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove the Id from the array of objects by filtering but the id is not removed. I have used the filter method then I am filtering object keys.

```js
const data= [{
    "id": 1,
    "group_name": "Science",
    "date": 2023,
    "created_table_at": "2022-08-20T01:22:40.000Z",
    "roll": "1401",
    "name": "Israt Jahan",

}]
const filteredData = data.filter((result) =>
          Object.keys(result)
            .filter((key) => key !== "id")
            .reduce((obj, key) => {
              obj[key] = result[key];
              return obj;
            }, {})
        );
console.log(filteredData)
```

My Expected output:

```
[{
        "group_name": "Science",
        "date": 2023,
        "created_table_at": "2022-08-20T01:22:40.000Z",
        "roll": "1401",
        "name": "Israt Jahan",

    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter is for filtering an element in an array, instead you can use map, where we clone the original object, then delete the property we don't want, also this solution only deletes a single property, not multiple ones!

```js
const data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "group_name": "Science",
  "date": 2023,
  "created_table_at": "2022-08-20T01:22:40.000Z",
  "roll": "1401",
  "name": "Israt Jahan",

}]
const filteredData = data.map(x => {
 const cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
 delete cloned.id;
 return cloned;
});
console.log(filteredData)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this solution:

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  group_name: 'Science',
  date: 2023,
  created_table_at: '2022-08-20T01:22:40.000Z',
  roll: '1401',
  name: 'Israt Jahan'
}];

/**
 * For each object in the data array, keep everything except the id.
 */
const filteredData = data.map(({ id, ...rest }) => rest);

console.log(filteredData);
```